# Represent a number with a color, difference not enough for percentage based rgb

Tags: javascript, math, rgb

I have an array (1200 values) of numbers

`[123, 145, 158, 133...]`

I'd like to have a div for each value with a background color from red to green, red being the smallest number and green the largest.

The base setup looks like this: (templating with vuejs but unrelated to the problem)

```
const values = [123, 145, 158, 133...]; // 1200 values inside
const total = values.length;

<div
  v-for="(val, i) in values"
  :key="i"
  :style="{backgroundColor: `rgb(${(100 - (val*100/total)) * 256}, ${(val*100/total) * 256}, 0)`}">
  {{val}}
</div>
```

I'm not a maths specialist but since all my numbers are around 100, the rgb generated is the same. (around 12% yellowish color)

How can I give more weight to the difference between 137 and 147?

EDIT: final formula:

```
:style="{backgroundColor: `rgb(${(256/(maxValue-minValue) * (boule-maxValue) - 255)}, ${(256/20 * (boule-maxValue) + 255)}, 0)`}"
```

[image: result]

Comment: Use your min value as 0% / 0 and your max value as 100% / 255. `255 * (val-minVal)/(maxVal-minVal)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkout this post: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/70801/how-to-normalize-data-to-0-1-range.

Basically you want to linearly rescale your values to another interval. You need your current `min` and `max` values from the array. Then define the new `min'` and `max'` which are the limits of the new interval. This would be `[0, 255]` in your case.

To do the transformation use the formula:
`newvalue= (max'-min')/(max-min)*(value-max)+max'`

As an example:
If your `min` value is 127 and `max` is 147, and you want to map 137. Then:
`256/20 * (137-147) + 255` which results in 127.

If you want to map 130. Then:
`256/20 * (130-147) + 255 = 37.4`.

Comment: It tends more towards the black/red than the yellow/green but this works beautifully.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what meaning those values actually have

However, you can try this: if your values are always bigger than 100 and always less than 150 (you can choose these number of course) you can "stretch" your values using the values as minimum and maximum. Let's take 137 and 147 as examples:

```
(val-min) : (max-min) = x : 255

(137-100):(150-100) = x:255  ->  37:50 = x:255  ->  188

(147-100):(150-100) = x:255  ->  47:50 = x:255  ->  239
```

That is for the math. In the end, this is the calculation:

```
newValue = (val-min)*255/(max-min)
```

where min and max are your chosen values.

Answer (score 1):

You could take a kind of magnifier for a range of data. In this example, the values between 20 and 30 are mapped to a two times greater range than the outside values inside of an interval of 0 ... 100.

```js
function magnifier(value, start, end, factor) {
    var middle = (start + end) / 2,
        size = (end - start) * factor / 2,
        left = middle - size,
        right = middle + size;

    if (value <= start) return value * left / start;
    if (value <= end) return (value - start) * factor + left;
    return (value - end) * (100 - right) / (100 - end) + right;
}

var i;

for (i = 0; i <= 100; i += 5) {
    console.log(i, magnifier(i, 20, 30, 2));
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```